How to Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(x) - \ln(1+x) - \sqrt{1+2x}}{x^2}$ Without L'Hôpital or Taylor Expansion?
it's my first Analysis class in college. I'm trying to evaluate the following limit:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(x) - \ln(1+x) - \sqrt{1+2x}}{x^2}$$
but I would like to avoid using L'Hôpital's Rule or Taylor series expansions.
Is there a more "direct" or classical method to approach this limit? Perhaps by using other mathematical tools? Any insights or detailed steps would be greatly appreciated.

L'Hôpital and Taylor are the classical approaches in this case, I don't see how you would solve it in another way

Using Taylor expansion is the best strategy here, why do you want to avoid it?

You can get rid of $\cos x$ by subtracting and adding  $1$ in the numerator and by applying $$\cos x-1=-{\sin^2x\over 1+\cos x}$$ But with remaining part of the numerator $1-\ln(1+x)-\sqrt{1+2x}$ I do not see an elementary way for solving the limit.

Isn't "analyzing the dominant terms" the same as using Taylor expansion?

It's what the professor told us. He prohibited us from using those techniques.

Please include your Approach.

Hint:
$$\dfrac{\cos x-\ln(1+x)-\sqrt{1+2x}}{x^2}$$
$$=-\dfrac{1-\cos x}{x^2}-\dfrac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x^2}+\dfrac{1-x-\sqrt{1+2x}}{x^2}$$
The first one is easy and should be left as an exercise.
For the second one, use Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion .
For the third, rationalize the numerator.

It should be $-ln(1+x)$ not $ln(1+x)$

@CHOSM, Thanks for your observation

and $1+x-\sqrt{1+2x}$ should be $1-x-\sqrt{1+2x}$ now

@CHOSM, Thanks again, for a finite result, we should have $$\sqrt{1-2x}$$

You don’t need to think to far, look at the questions more carefully and you’ll see that you don’t need L'Hôpital's Rule or Taylor series expansion to solve this problem
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(x) - \ln(1+x) - \sqrt{1+2x}}{x^2}$$
The sum (or minus) at the numerator doesn’t matter because the three functions are expected to relate to each other and cancel out the factor $\frac{1}{x}$ or powers of it
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \{ \frac{\cos(x) }{x^2}- \frac{\ln(1+x) }{x^2}-\frac{\sqrt{1+2x} }{x^2} \}$$
By observation none of the three parts contains $x^2$ in their numerator and obviously all three diverges, even if you’re not sure of the $\cos()$ part and $\ln()$ part see that $\sqrt()$ part
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{ \frac{1}{x^4}+\frac{2}{x^3} }$$
It contains the forbidden $\frac{1}{x}$ and because the limit is held by a sum, if one part diverges so does the rest
Tell your Professor the limit doesn’t exist as it diverges to infinity

Thank you so much guys for your prompt answers.
Thanks to the answer of lab bhattacharjee , I have come to the solution:
To evaluate:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos x - \ln(1+x) - \sqrt{1+2x}}{x^2},
$$
without using L’Hôpital's Rule or Taylor expansion, we can proceed by decomposing the expression as follows:
$$
\frac{\cos x - \ln(1+x) - \sqrt{1+2x}}{x^2} =
\frac{1 - \cos x}{x^2} + \frac{-\ln(1+x) + x}{x^2} + \frac{1 - x - \sqrt{1+2x}}{x^2}.
$$
Now, let’s handle each term separately.

1. $\frac{1 - \cos x}{x^2}$
This is a well-known trigonometric limit:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos x}{x^2} = -\frac{1}{2}.
$$

2. $\frac{-\ln(1+x) + x}{x^2}$
This limit has been tackled here and it is equal to $\frac{1}{2}.$

3. $\frac{1 - x - \sqrt{1+2x}}{x^2}$
For this term, we are going to multiply the numerator and denominator by the conjugate $(1 - x + \sqrt{1+2x})$:
$$
\frac{1 - x - \sqrt{1+2x}}{x^2} = \frac{(1 - x - \sqrt{1+2x})(1 - x + \sqrt{1+2x})}{x^2(1 - x + \sqrt{1+2x})} = \frac{x^2 - 4x}{x^2(1 - x + \sqrt{1+2x})}. = \frac{x-4}{x(1 - x + \sqrt{1+2x})}.
$$
As $x \to 0$, the denominator $x(1 - x + \sqrt{1+2x}) \to 0$, while the numerator $(x-4) \to -4$. Thus, this term diverges to $\infty$.

Now combine all terms:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos x - \ln(1+x) - \sqrt{1+2x}}{x^2} = \infty.
$$
